# How can i remove/delete a repo i cloned from git?

Tags: repository, delete

I cloned a repo twice, first, I cloned at home. second, I created a folder and cloned it again in the folder. now I cannot delete any of the repo...even the folder I created. Any soln?

Comment: How are you trying to delete the folder? Using `rm -rf folder`?

Comment: @GMaster i just tried rmdir... and i also tried like your comment code ....but failed to delete.

Comment: @GMaster Yo dude... i ve done it... like your code.... thanks man... i was trying without "sudo" ...thats why i cannot made it. now i used sudo...and i made it. THanks again.

Comment: Nice. `rmdir` deletes empty folder(s), `rmdir` will not delete folder(s) if there are files or subfolders inside